# What is default log levels for Kubernetes storage sidecars

Tags: kubernetes, log-level, klog

What would be default log level for Kubernetes storage sidecars such as external-snapshotter, external-provisioner, external-attacher etc. I couldnt get details from code (checked external-snapshotter) code. Is there a way to know default log level that gets set.

Answer (score 0):

You should find `klog.V(5)` in the source as well as [--v=5](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/blob/master/deploy/kubernetes/snapshot-controller/setup-snapshot-controller.yaml#L38) in the deployment spec.

Answer (score 0):

Like `gohm'c` said you can get the information from the deployment files and you can also use kubectl commands for getting the verbose level. The command looks like this

Kubectl get deployments -v (level)

By using the verbose level arguments you can filter out the deployments and find the log level for respective deployments and if you don’t want to use default verbose level you can also mention -v tag and level while creating the deployment.

This [document](https://www.shellhacks.com/kubectl-debug-increase-verbosity/#:%7E:text=While%20troubleshooting%20Kubernetes%2Drelated%20issues,that%20represents%20the%20log%20level.) outlines a few cases where we can use verbose